# What is the use of autofac.webapi2 in Azure Bot Framework integration with Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, .net-core, botframework, azure-cosmosdb, chatbot

I was going through this MSDN documentation for Integration of Cosmos DB with our Azure Chat Bot. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

They have told to install the NuGet package called **autofac.webapi2**. But I am not getting the actual reason to use it in Azure Chat Bot. No documentation is provided for the same.

With its name autofac.webapi2 I guess it has WebApi features, but the Bot Framework is in .Net Core.

If any one could tell what is it for would be a great help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Was my answer sufficient? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Yes, it was helpful and thank you so much. I apologize I was busy in some other imp. work and didn't notice this. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to why that specific package is mentioned in that documentation; it isn't needed for the sample code. If you can add Cosmos to your bot without compile errors, I wouldn't worry about it. Eventually, Visual Studio will let you know if you need it. [Here's the `autofac.webapi` documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html), if you want it.

That being said, you should not be developing or expanding v3 bots right now. [It's been deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3#v3-deprecation-notification). If your v3 is currently working, it will continue to work. However I cannot express enough that if you are putting any semi-significant amount of effort towards updating/expanding/changing your v3 bot, you'd be better off spending that time [migrating to v4](https://aka.ms/v3v4-bot-migration).